# react-native run-android build error Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:x.y.z

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-2.3

Here's my error:

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:x.y.z.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>             file:/Users/arronlinton/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base/x.y.z/play-services-base-x.y.z.pom

Going off of what it's saying it can't find, is that suggesting I need to install something locally and/or perhaps via Android SDK Manager?

Or would this require me to edit my build.gradle?
Need any additional information?

-

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1" 
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        // mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        //     name 'Google'
        }
          maven {
        url 'http://artifactory.raksdtd.com/artifactory/libs-release'
    }

        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'

        // classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}

        maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }

     configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
            force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
        }
      }   

    subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "x.y.z"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Ensure that your top-level build.gradle contains a reference to the google() repo or to maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }.

Answer (score 0):

Change dependency declaration as follows

from

```
compile
```

to

```
implementation
```

Also check in our root gradle file contains jcenter and maven repo like as follows

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://artifactory.raksdtd.com/artifactory/libs-release'
    }

    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}
```

}

Comment: Yup all my dependencies are declared with implementation and I'm still receiving this error.

Comment: check your maven or jcenter is there on your root gradle file?

Comment: I updated the post with my build.gradle file. maven and jcenter is all there and I'm still receiving the same error.